# map bind with ng-model not updating data

Tags: angularjs, dictionary

I called REST service which gives me an Object contains a map.
Map in java looks like Map

Following is my js

```
$scope.marks = {};
//get data from rest

StudentService.query().$promise.then(function(data) 
{
  $scope.students = data;
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.students.length;i++){
  var obj = $scope.students[i];
  //marks (key=studentName, value=mark in decimal)
  $scope.marks[obj["studentName"]]=0.0;
}
```

following is my html

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,value) in marks">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="key" disabled>

{{marks[key]}} <!-- Here it is not updating value from above model-->

    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="value">


</div>
```

When I update value in textfield it is not update value displayed just below textfiled ie `{{marks[key]}}` is not showing updated value. Please correct me if wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are passing to the `ng-model` is just a string, which is immutable. You need to define the `ng-model` like this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="marks[key]">
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.marks = {
      mark1: 1,
      mark2: 2,
      mark3: 3
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,value) in marks">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="key" disabled>{{marks[key]}}
    <!-- Here it is not updating value from above model-->

    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="marks[key]">

  </div>
</div>
```